# Function call with IP address as argument

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm working on a scraper that checks progress for file transfers, which operates off a pickled list of IP addresses. When a file is complete, I want the IP address to be removed from the pickled list of IPs and moved to a separate pickled list, "complete".

Beginning:

```
servers = {"10.10.10.1": "", "10.10.10.2": "", "10.10.10.3": ""}
skeys = servers.keys()
complete = []

def donewith(server):
    if server in skeys:
        complete.append("{0}".format(server))
        servers.pop("{0}".format(server))
        logging.info('Moved {0} to Complete list.'.format(server))
    else:
        logging.error('Unable to move \'{0}\' to Complete list.'.format(server))
```

Desired result:

```
donewith(10.10.10.1)

servers = {"10.10.10.2": "", "10.10.10.3": ""}
complete = ["10.10.10.1"]
```

This is what I actually get.

```
donewith(10.10.10.1)
File "<stdin>", line 1
donewith(10.10.10.1)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Alternatively calling the function with quotes produces a `TypeError requiring an integer.` Not quite sure how to work around this, since it seems like such a simple problem

Elaboration on quotation solution:

```
def check(server):
    #print "Checking {0}".format(server)
    logging.info('Fetching {0}.'.format(server))
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+server+"/avicapture.html")
    tall = response.read() # puts the data into a string
    html = tall.rstrip()
    match = re.search('.*In Progress \((.*)%\).*', html)
    if match:
        temp = match.group(1)
        results = temp
        servers[server] = temp
        if int(temp) >= 98 and int(temp) <= 99:
            abort(server)
            alertmail(temp, server)
            donewith(server)
            logging.info('{0} completed.'.format(server))
        return str(temp)
    else:
        logging.error('Unable to find progress for file on {0}.'.format(server))
        return None
```

THis function calls the `donewith()` function, which doesn't work if the function has quotes like: `donewith("server")`.

Example:

```
def check(server):
     donewith("server")

def donewith(server)
     do_things.

check(server)
```

Resulting in..

```
check(10.10.10.3)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Always with the zero in the third set of digits...

Comment: You have to pass value in string only as you mention with quotes. Will you please provide traceback of `TypeError: requireding an integer` ?

Comment: Please provide full traceback insted of 2-3 line from tracback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up with this. It was neglected in other answers that a function can't call another function with an IP address as the arg due to the number of periods making it not a string. Even calling func(str(ip)) within the func did not work.

I took a different tactic and decided to target the index of the entry, instead of the entry name itself.

Solution:

```
servers = {"10.10.10.1": "", "10.10.10.2": "", "10.10.10.3": ""}
skeys = servers.keys() # Creates list of dictionary keys (IP addresses)
["10.10.10.1", "10.10.10.2", "10.10.10.3"]

for i, j in enumerate(skeys): # Find the index
    if j == server:
        skeys.pop(i) # Pop the index.

servers = servers.fromkeys(skeys, "") # Recreates server dict from skeys.
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is a string. you should do like this:

```
    donewith('10.10.10.1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired behavior is not possible as it is, because `10.10.10.1` is not a string, and as python sees dots `.`, it tries to parse it as float, but float can only have one decimal fraction, thats why exception points to number after second dot.

To make it work you'll need to pass argument as string:

```
donewith("10.10.10.1")

servers = {"10.10.10.2": "", "10.10.10.3": ""}
complete = ["10.10.10.1"]
```

and not only in `donewith`, but in `check` too:

```
def check(server): # here server is variable name, not a string
    donewith(server)

def donewith(server)
    do_things.

check(server) # server = "10.10.10.1"
# or
check("10.10.10.1")
```

because it's how python works, you need to declare strings in quotes, or else it will be treated as number (first character is digit) or variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
In [6]: def donewith(server):
...:         if server in skeys:
...:                 complete.append(server)
...:                 servers.pop(server)
...:                 logging.info('Moved {0} to Complete list.'.format(server))
...:         else:
...:                 logging.error('Unable to move \'{0}\' to Complete list.'.format(server))
...:

In [7]: donewith("10.10.10.1")

In [8]:

In [8]: servers
Out[8]: {'10.10.10.2': '', '10.10.10.3': ''}
```

Comment: I know this method works, but the issue is the call for the donewith(server) function lies within another function, where placing single or double quotes isn't working.